# reflexive ideal in regular local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, regular-rings

Let $I$ be an ideal of a regular local ring $R$ such that $I$ is reflexive as an $R$-module (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AUY) .

Then is $I$ a principal ideal (i.e. a free $R$-module i.e. a cyclic $R$-module) ?

Comment: This is correct. Any ideal $I$ can be written as $i=xJ$ with $J$ of height at least 2.  Also, the reflexive hypothesis implies $J$ is and then $J=R$.

Comment: @Mohan: why is $J=R$ ?

Comment: I suggest you look up a book (for example, Serre's local algebra, where $R_1, S_2$ conditions are dealt with).